# Android Mediaplayer can't get playback-buffering progress when pausing (API 19+)

Tags: android, media-player

Android Mediaplayer can't get the buffering progress when pausing(API 19+)

I am using Mediaplayer of Android (API 19+) to play video. But when I pause the Mediaplayer (by `mp.pasue()`), I can't get the progress of the playback buffering.

For example, before pausing, the progress of the buffer is at 5%, and then it will not change.

In fact, the `onBufferingUpdate` callback function

```
public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent)
```

will not be called when Mediaplayer is pausing. I tried to use `VideoView` instead, but when I call `getBufferPercentage()`, it will always get 5% when pausing.

What's more, Mediaplayer doesn't seem to pause buffering of the content, because when I restart the player after a while,
the buffering progress suddenly jumps to 100%. I'm sure it's not possible this video can be buffered so fast!

This problem doesn't appear on Android API 18 (or lower).
Can anyone tell me how to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Interesting question!